# How do I tackle lifetimes in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, ownership

I am having issues with the concept of lifetimes in rust. I am trying to use the crate bgpkit_parser to read in a bz2 file via url link and then create a radix trie.

One field extracted from the file is the AS Path which I have named `path` in my code within the `build_routetable` function. I am having trouble as to why rust does not like `let origin = clean_path.last()` which takes the last element in the vector.

```
fn as_parser(element: &BgpElem) -> Vec<u32> {
    let x = &element.as_path.as_ref().unwrap().segments[0];
    let mut as_vec = &Vec::new();
    let mut as_path: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    if let AsPathSegment::AsSequence(value) = x {
        as_vec = value;
    }
    for i in as_vec {
        as_path.push(i.asn); 
    }
    return as_path;
}

fn prefix_parser(element: &BgpElem) -> String {
    let subnet_id = element.prefix.prefix.ip().to_string().to_owned();
    let prefix_id = element.prefix.prefix.prefix().to_string().to_owned();
    let prefix = format!("{}/{}", subnet_id, prefix_id);//.as_str();
    return prefix;
}

fn get_aspath(raw_aspath: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut as_path = Vec::new();
    for i in raw_aspath {
        if i < 64511 {
            if as_path.contains(&i) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                as_path.push(i);
            }
        }
        else if 65535 < i && i < 4000000000 {
            if as_path.contains(&i) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                as_path.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return as_path;
}

fn build_routetable(mut trie4: Trie<String, Option<&u32>>, mut trie6: Trie<String, Option<&u32>>) {
    let url: &str = "http://archive.routeviews.org/route-views.chile/\
        bgpdata/2022.06/RIBS/rib.20220601.0000.bz2";
    let parser = BgpkitParser::new(url).unwrap();
    let mut count = 0;
    for elem in parser {
        if elem.elem_type == bgpkit_parser::ElemType::ANNOUNCE {
            let record_timestamp = &elem.timestamp;
            let record_type = "A";
            let peer = &elem.peer_ip;
            let prefix = prefix_parser(&elem);
            let path = as_parser(&elem);
            let clean_path = get_aspath(path);
            
            // Issue is on the below line
            // `clean_path` does not live long enough
            // borrowed value does not live long
            // enough rustc E0597
            // main.rs(103, 9): `clean_path` dropped 
            // here while still borrowed 
            // main.rs(77, 91): let's call the
            // lifetime of this reference `'1` 
            // main.rs(92, 17): argument requires 
            // that `clean_path` is borrowed for `'1`
            
            let origin = clean_path.last(); //issue line
            if prefix.contains(":") {
                trie6.insert(prefix, origin);
            }
            else {
                trie4.insert(prefix, origin);
            }
            count+=1;
            if count >= 10000 {
                println!("{:?} | {:?} | {:?} | {:?} | {:?}", 
                record_type, record_timestamp, peer, prefix, path);
                count=0
            }
        };
    }
    println!("Trie4 size: {:?} prefixes", trie4.len());
    println!("Trie6 size: {:?} prefixes", trie6.len());
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you're "inserting" a reference.  But what's being referenced doesn't outlive what it's being inserted into.

Longer:  The hint is your `trie4` argument, the signature of which is this:

```rust
mut trie4: Trie<String, Option<&u32>>
```

So that lives beyond the length of the loop where things are declared.  This is all in the loop:

```rust
let origin = clean_path.last(); //issue line
if prefix.contains(":") {
    trie6.insert(prefix, origin);
}
```

While `origin` is a `Vec<u32>` and that's fine, the `insert` method is no doubt taking a `String` and either an `Option<&u32>` or a `&u32`.  Obviously a key/value pair.  But here's your problem: the *value* has to live as long as the collection, but your value is the last element contained in the `Vec<u32>`, which goes away!  So you can't put something into it that will not live as long as the "container" object!  Rust has just saved you from dangling references (just like it's supposed to).

Basically, your containers should be `Trie<String, Option<u32>>` *without* the reference, and then this'll all just work fine.  Your problem is that the elements are references, and not just contained regular values, and given the size of what you're containing, it's actually smaller to contain a `u32` than a reference (pointer size (though actually, it'll *likely* be the same either way, because alignment issues)).

Also of note: `trie4` and `trie6` will both be gone at the end of this function call, because they were moved into this function (not references or mutable references).  I hope that's what you want.